# Add a part of value from file1 to column in file 2 if there is a match

Tags: awk, r

I have 2 csv files:

file (1 column)1:

```
Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Myoviridae
Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae
Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Siphoviridae
Prokaryote,Ligamenvirales,Lipothrixviridae
Prokaryote,Ligamenvirales,Rudiviridae
Prokaryote,Unassigned,Ampullaviridae
```

and
file 2 (2 columns):

```
NC_038375   Baculoviridae,Betabaculovirus,Trichoplusia_ni_granulovirus
NC_000867   Corticoviridae,Corticovirus,Pseudoalteromonas_virus_PM2
NC_000866   Myoviridae,Tequatrovirus,Escherichia_virus_T4
NC_000929   Myoviridae,Muvirus,Escherichia_virus_Mu
NC_004166   Siphoviridae,,Bacillus_phage_SPP1
NC_005859   Siphoviridae,Tequintavirus,Escherichia_virus_T5
NC_002166   Siphoviridae,Hendrixvirus,Escherichia_virus_HK022
NC_008720   Podoviridae,Enquatrovirus,Escherichia_virus_N4
NC_002371   Podoviridae,Lederbergvirus,Salmonella_virus_P22
NC_011048   Podoviridae,Salasvirus,Bacillus_virus_phi29
NNC_001929  Geminiviridae,Begomovirus,Abutilon_mosaic_virus
NC_002649   Podoviridae,Salasvirus,Bacillus_virus_GA1
```

I would like to add 2 first names from file 1 at the begining of each value in second column file 2 if there is a match based on the third name in fname. eg:
desired output:

```
NC_038375   Baculoviridae,Betabaculovirus,Trichoplusia_ni_granulovirus
    NC_000867   Corticoviridae,Corticovirus,Pseudoalteromonas_virus_PM2
    NC_000866   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Myoviridae,Tequatrovirus,Escherichia_virus_T4
    NC_000929   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Myoviridae,Muvirus,Escherichia_virus_Mu
    NC_004166   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Siphoviridae,,Bacillus_phage_SPP1
    NC_005859   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Siphoviridae,Tequintavirus,Escherichia_virus_T5
    NC_002166   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Siphoviridae,Hendrixvirus,Escherichia_virus_HK022
    NC_008720   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Enquatrovirus,Escherichia_virus_N4
    NC_002371   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Lederbergvirus,Salmonella_virus_P22
    NC_011048   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Salasvirus,Bacillus_virus_phi29
    NNC_001929  Geminiviridae,Begomovirus,Abutilon_mosaic_virus
    NC_002649   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Salasvirus,Bacillus_virus_GA1
```

any help with that?

Comment: Is the indenting in the output an error? (If so, please edit and correct.)

Comment: So you want to match 3rd column from file1 to the first value in the 2nd column in file2?

Comment: Also, is file 2 tab- or space(s)-delimited?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!!!!

Comment: file 2 is tab separated

Comment: And the indenting? (Please also edit in the tab-delimited information.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an affermative to my question above, you could do it like this in `awk`:

*parse.awk*

```c
FNR == NR {              # Only for the first file
  h[$3] = $1 "," $2      # Collect column one and two into 'h' hash
  next
}

{ split($2, a, ",") }    # Split the second column of the second file to array 'a'

a[1] in h {              # If the first element of the second column of the 
  $2 = h[a[1]] "," $2    # second file is in 'h' then prepend the value to $2
}

1                        # Print all lines
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk FS=',' file1 FS='\t' OFS='\t' file2
```

Output:

```
NC_038375   Baculoviridae,Betabaculovirus,Trichoplusia_ni_granulovirus
NC_000867   Corticoviridae,Corticovirus,Pseudoalteromonas_virus_PM2
NC_000866   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Myoviridae,Tequatrovirus,Escherichia_virus_T4
NC_000929   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Myoviridae,Muvirus,Escherichia_virus_Mu
NC_004166   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Siphoviridae,,Bacillus_phage_SPP1
NC_005859   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Siphoviridae,Tequintavirus,Escherichia_virus_T5
NC_002166   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Siphoviridae,Hendrixvirus,Escherichia_virus_HK022
NC_008720   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Enquatrovirus,Escherichia_virus_N4
NC_002371   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Lederbergvirus,Salmonella_virus_P22
NC_011048   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Salasvirus,Bacillus_virus_phi29
NNC_001929  Geminiviridae,Begomovirus,Abutilon_mosaic_virus
NC_002649   Prokaryote,Caudovirales,Podoviridae,Salasvirus,Bacillus_virus_GA1
```